# Perceptron de dos entradas

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de programar un percepton. Lo que debe hacer es reconocer cuando un `AND` es verdadero o falso, a través de dos datos de entrada y sus pesos, y al final imprimir la cantidad de intentos que fueron necesario para aprender. El problema es que sale del bucle antes de aprender correctamente.

```
class Program { 
    static void Main(string[] args) { 
      Program p = new Program();
      float peso1 , peso2, umbral;
      Random r = new Random();
      bool sw = false;
      int intento=0;

      while (!sw) { 
        sw = true;

        peso1 = Convert.ToSingle(r.NextDouble() - r.NextDouble());
        peso2 = Convert.ToSingle(r.NextDouble() - r.NextDouble());
        umbral = Convert.ToSingle(r.NextDouble() - r.NextDouble());

        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------"); 
        Console.WriteLine("Peso 1: " + peso1); 
        Console.WriteLine("Peso 2: " + peso2); 
        Console.WriteLine("Umbral: " + umbral); 
        Console.WriteLine("E1:1 E2:1 : " + p.funcion(p.neurona(1f, 1f, peso1, peso2, umbral))); 
        Console.WriteLine("E1:1 E2:0 : " + p.funcion(p.neurona(1f, 1f, peso1, peso2, umbral))); 
        Console.WriteLine("E1:0 E2:1 : " + p.funcion(p.neurona(1f, 1f, peso1, peso2, umbral))); 
        Console.WriteLine("E1:0 E2:0 : " + p.funcion(p.neurona(1f, 1f, peso1, peso2, umbral)));

        if (p.funcion(p.neurona(1f, 1f, peso1, peso2, umbral)) != 1) {
          sw = false; 
        }

        if (p.funcion(p.neurona(1f, 0f, peso1, peso2, umbral)) != 0) { 
          sw = false; 
        }

        if (p.funcion(p.neurona(0f, 1f, peso1, peso2, umbral)) != 0) {  
          sw = false; 
        }

        if (p.funcion(p.neurona(0f, 0f, peso1, peso2, umbral)) != 0) {  
          sw = false; 
        }

        intento = intento + 1; 
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Me tomo " + intento + " aprender ");

    }

    float neurona(float entrada1, float entrada2, float peso1, float peso2, float umbral) { 
        return umbral + entrada1 * peso1 + entrada2 * peso2; 
    }

    float funcion (float d) { return d > 0 ? 1 : 0; }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué sumas el umbral?  ¿no deberías comprobar si `d` es mayor al umbral en lugar de mayor que cero?

Comment: no, el umbral o sesgo lo uso como termino independiente de la funcion no como un limite que debe cumplir el valor de la funcion, pero ya los solucione gracias